# Briefly show then hide an element after custom validation in Angular.js

Tags: angularjs, coffeescript

I want to briefly show (for a second or two) a 'looks good!' message next to a text box after some server-side validation function has run.

I'm not certain of the "angular way" to do this. Additionally I haven't ventured into angular animation yet.

Here's my custom validation directive, for context.

```
module.directive 'serverValidation', ($http) ->
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: (scope, elem, attrs, ctrl) ->
        elem.on 'blur', (e) ->
            scope.$apply () -> $http.post('../api/validator', "val": elem.val())
                .success (data) ->
                    ctrl.$setValidity('myErrorKey', data.valid)
```

Thanks!

Comment: Is this coffeescript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your Html, you need a hidden div (ng-hide="showMe==false")

In your angular controller, you add a variable : $scope.showMe = false;

In your ".success", you change the value of the variable to true, and then, you set a timeout in javascript to set the variable back to false

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I suppose I am looking too hard.